# Problema con recaptcha y envío de formulario en php

Tags: php, html, captcha

Tengo un problema con el recaptcha y el envío de un formulario en php. Se valida bien el recaptcha, el problema está en el envío del formulario, podría ser que tuviera algo mal puesto o algún error en el código. Si alguien me pudiera decir en que parte tengo el error. Si valida el captcha, pero no logro que me envíe el correo.

Código de **contact.php**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
  <div class="contact-form">
    <form action="iniciocontacto.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your name here" require>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" value="" size="40" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" cols="40" rows="4" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha col-lg-6" data-sitekey="6Ldwk1EUAAAAAGz5f0OcRb1_sL7fZ6mOGlwA--b1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

Código de **iniciocontacto.php**:

```
<?php
  // AQUI EMPEZAMOS LA VALIDACION DEL RECAPTCHA DE GOOGLE
   $recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

     if($recaptcha != ''){
      $secret = "6Ldwk1EUAAAAAAjgg1VOsYjHI_3jh3B_Ypwv5pVg";
      $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     $var =       file_get_contents("https://wwww.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?     secret=$secret&response=$recaptcha&remoteip=$ip");
     $array = json_decode($var, true);

    if($array['success']){
      //true

      // Aqui empezamos con el envio del formulario de contacto
     header("Content-type: text/html;charset=\"utf-8\"");
   $error = ""; $mensajeExito = "";

    if ($_POST) {
     if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST["email"], 
    FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
         $error .= "E-mail no válido.<br>";   
   }
   if ($error != "") {
       $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><b>Se     generó un error:</b></p>' . $error . '</div>';
   } else {
       $nombre = $_POST['name'];
       $mail = $_POST['email'];
       $asunto = $_POST['subject'];
       $telefono = $_POST['phone'];
       $mensajeC = $_POST['message'];

       $header = 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
       $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
       $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

       $mensaje = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $nombre . ",\r\n";
       $mensaje .= "Su e-mail es: " . $mail . " \r\n";
       $mensaje .= "Asunto: " . $asunto . " \r\n";
       $mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $mensajeC . " \r\n";
       $mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

       $para = 'mi correo electronico';
       $asunto = 'Mensaje de su sitio web';

       if (mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header)) {
           $mensajeExito = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Mensaje enviado con éxito :)</div>'; 
           header('Location: index.php');   
       } else {
           $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>   <strong>Mensaje sin enviar :(</div>';  
       } 
      }  
      }
  // Aqui terminamos con el formulario de contacto
   } else {
        echo "Usted es un robot";
       }
     } else {
      echo "rellene todos los campos";
     }
  // AQUI TERMINALOS LA VALIDACION DEL CAPTCHA

  ?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, Juan. Consulta: ¿has depurado el código? Me refiero, a colocar sus `print` en cada parte de los procesos, a fin de saber si entra en tal o cual camino de la lógica. Porque dices que el problema es que no te envía el correo, ¿sabes en qué parte específica es que se detiene el flujo? Asumo por tu pregunta que no te arroja mensaje de error alguno, ¿o sí?

Comment: Mira si pongo solo el recaptcha por si solo si funciona, y si pongo el envío de correo en php funciona perfectamente si puedes observar por lo mismo lo tengo separado en que parte comienza el recaptcha y en que parte empieza para enviar los datos en php a el correo.

Comment: pero no se si inserte bien la parte del envío de correo en php con sus datos en el parte del recaptcha

Comment: A lo que me refiero que inserte la parte del php del envío de correo   en este if del recaptcha    // Aqui empezamos con el envio del formulario de contacto

Comment: Miren este es el enlace del formulario de contacto para que vean lo que hace http://muestra.hitech-webdesign.com/contact.php

Comment: la completo el recaptcha me pone el mensaje Usted es un robot